# ServiceWorker ifs to define specific cache for specific content

Tags: javascript, service-worker

My website have 6 different content elements that I want to control by service worker specific cache methods.

1. **[precache]** STATIC CONTENT (css, js, fonts)
2. **[cache fallback to network]** CDN (images from CloudFront S3)
3. **[network fallback to cache]** INDEX (main page)
4. **[cache fallback to network]** PAGES (domain.com/sth -> html)
5. **[pass]** API (ajax calls)
6. **[pass]** OTHER STUFF (analytics, tag manager)

I made 6 ifs inside ServiceWorker fetch event.

My question is... Is it a good approach? Not methods... because it's specific to my website/blog. But what do you think about that ifs? Is it a right way to filter specific content and use proper cache?

```
var domain = location.host.split('.')[0]

regexStatic = new RegExp('https://' + location.host + '/build/(.*)')
regexCdn = new RegExp('https://cdn.' + domain + '(.*)')
regexIndex = new RegExp('https://' + location.host + '/')
regexApi = new RegExp('https://' + location.host + '/api/(.*)')
regexPages = new RegExp('https://' + location.host + '/(.*)')

self.addEventListener('fetch', function (event) {
  // STATIC
  if (regexStatic.test(event.request.url)) {
    event.respondWith(
      //
    )
    return
  }

  // CDN
  if (regexCdn.test(event.request.url)) {
    event.respondWith(
      //
    )
    return
  }

  // INDEX
  if (regexIndex.test(event.request.url)) {
    event.respondWith(
      //
    )
    return
  }

  // API
  if (regexApi.test(event.request.url)) {
    return
  }

  // PAGES
  if (regexPages.test(event.request.url)) {
    event.respondWith(
      //
    )
    return
  }

  // OTHER
  console.log('NOT INCLUDED IN CACHE: ', event.request.url)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you dividing the content.

If the content is not found in cache it will automatically get forwarded to network for fetch, otherwise local cache copy is served.

Just check `content-type` while making API calls and don't cache those responses.

Just divide the content into two categories.. `Cache-able`/  `Non Cache-able`.

> Get more here :
>   https://github.com/GoogleChrome/samples/tree/gh-pages/service-worker